# Getting Firestore Document with ID same as UID fails

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Trying to access Firestore document having uid as it's id fails, document isn't found.

I have a really simple setup and trying to learn Vue and utilising Firebase functionalities. I'm successfully using Firebase authentication but when trying to access Document in Firestore, which's id is the same as uid for the user, document isn't found.

Security rules are set as open as possible, so that they shouldn't cause problem (you shouldn't use this in production):

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
        allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Js code for firebase

```
firebase.initializeApp(config)

// firebase utils
const db = firebase.firestore()

// firebase collections
const usersCollection = db.collection('users')

usersCollection.doc('testid').get().then((userSnapshot) => {
  if (userSnapshot.exists) {
    console.log('User data:', userSnapshot.data())
  } else {
    console.log('No such document!')
  }
}
```

Running previous code succeeds and I get data from Firestore for the Document with id ***testid***. But when I substitute the ***testid*** with uid of the user 
***KmJ9JC5Zb0O45d8xcndVgAowIzF2***, document isn't found.

Data should be fine in Firestore:

[Link to image showing Firestore data](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1TZM6OajtcGn_sNcvNAf1NL1xMk-Aey8n) (couldn't add image directly here beacuse don't have enough reputation... :)

The mistake must be really simple but I've been banging my head with this problem for a while and decided to ask the community.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be related to the path.

Try this approach instead of using `db.collection('users').doc('uid')`

```
const userData = await firebase
  .firestore()
  .doc(`users/${userToken.uid}`)
  .get();

console.log(userData.data());
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hey Ryan. Thanks helping to solve the problem. It seems that it isn't possible to call doc directly for firestore. So still stuck with this problem. Of course I could add id parameter to User model, but I think it would be more elegant to access user document directly with uid.

Comment: And it is really strange that for **testid** retrieving documents works that way. So something strange happening with that uid.

Comment: Hmm... really strange. I was able to add second document with exactly same id 'KmJ9JC5Zb0O45d8xcndVgAowIzF2'. First document was added when I created the collection in Firebase console. Adding third with same id fails because document with same id already exists.